# Backup for your production database into slave

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, database-backups

I need to take back up my database. I am using [Linode](http://linode.com). I am taking automated daily back up that linode provides. I am  using [BackupMyApp](http://BackupMyApp.com) to take a daily back up.

I want to create a slave too, every 1-2 mins (real time) it just keep on creating a image (master/slave) for my production database. Any plugin/gem for that.

Comment: `slave` suggests replication, and replication means data on slave is being kept up-to-date with data on master in real time

Comment: @Mchl 1 or 2 min delay is fine for me.. And if there is really some awesome plugin that offers real time stuff then i dont mind using that one too.

Comment: It's not a plugin. It's how you configure MySQL. See wonk0's answer

Answer (score 1):

You want to use MySQLs built-in replication:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication.html